# Win32_LogonSession returns incorrect value

Tags: c#, wmi

No amount of googling has gotten me anywhere with this.

I have the following code that checks if user(s) are logged on to a PC either via console or RDP.

It runs OK but the issue is that after the user logs off, WMI (or something somewhere) still thinks that they are logged on, and in this case, returns `true`, when it should return `false`.

If I reboot the PC it goes back to 0 until I login.

I am prepared to accept that this might be a bug within WMI, so if anyone has a better alternative to achieve the same thing I would massively appreciate the advice.

```
public bool PCInUse(string Hostname)
{
    ConnectionOptions connection = new ConnectionOptions();
    connection.Username = "username;
    connection.Password = "password";

    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + Hostname + "\\root\\CIMV2", connection);
    try
    {
        scope.Connect();
        var Query = new SelectQuery("SELECT LogonId FROM Win32_LogonSession Where (LogonType= 10) or (LogonType= 2)");
        var Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, Query);

        if (Searcher.Get().Count > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
     }
     catch
     {
         return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? You want to know if anyone is logged on?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (assuming your process is running as a service under local system or some privileged account) would be to get all running processes, make a list of distinct User Names for those processes (excluding all the system accounts like "SYSTEM", "NETWORK SERVICE", "LOCAL SERVICE") and any remaining unique userIds of the types you included in your "where" clause on the WMI query ought to give you some idea. Sure, it's possible someone might setup a service to run under a user account, and that might screw it up for you, and on servers running IIS or some other application that creates special user accounts, you might have to work around excluding those also.

You might have to include the inverse of your WMI query above to get the list of non-interactive sessions and the userIds associated with them to know what all to exclude.  You might also just look for those processes that you know are only in use by an interactive session (like "dwm.exe" and "explorer.exe").